# How to copy all the rows of selected column from one excel file to another using C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, spreadsheet, excel-interop

I am using this code, but since I want to copy a whole row with particular attribute and I don't know the count of totals rows.

```
        Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();

        srcPath = "C:\\Users\\sn314708\\Desktop\\Excel\\1.xlsx";
        Excel.Workbook srcworkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(srcPath);
        Excel.Worksheet srcworkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)srcworkBook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

        destPath = "C:\\Users\\sn314708\\Desktop\\Excel\\2.xlsx";
        Excel.Workbook destworkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(destPath, 0, false);
        Excel.Worksheet destworkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)destworkBook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

        Excel.Range from = srcworkSheet.Range["A1:C100"];
        Excel.Range to = destworkSheet.Range["A1:C100"];


        from.Copy(to);

        destworkBook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\sn314708\\Desktop\\Excel\\2 " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") + ".xlsx");
```

Comment: all the rows of column have data? no empty values in the column?

Answer (score 1):

either you fix the max number of rows you want to copy, or you could find the last row used in the whole sheet (i think its better). A sample you could do:

```
int lastUsedRow = srcworkSheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                     System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                     XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                     false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Row;


int colIndex = 1;
for(int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= lastUsedRow; rowIndex++ )
{
    destworkSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex] = srcworkSheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex];
}
```

index of row and column always start at 1.